# Как сделать выборку по значению из JSON

Tags: postgresql

Имеется таблица с полем типа `json`. Таблица заполнена значениями вида `[123,854,12]`, `[]`, `[12,2142141,24]`
Как мне выбрать строку, в json которой содержится определенное число?
Т.е. если я ищу `12`, то я должен получить две строки со значениями, перечисленными выше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы задействуете PostgreSQL вам разумнее воспользоваться не `JSON`, a типом `ARRAY`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id INTEGER,
  name INTEGER ARRAY
);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, '{123,854,12}');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, '{}');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (3, '{12,2142141,24}');
```

Тогда для поиска строк, в массиве `name` которых имеется значение 12 можно воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 12 = ANY (name);
 id |      name
----+-----------------
  1 | {123,854,12}
  3 | {12,2142141,24}
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему `json`, а не `jsonb`? Или вообще `int[]`, если допустимо немного изменить формат хранения?

Есть одна неочевидная проблема. Наивное решение `where fieldname ? 12` - нет такого оператора. А `where fieldname ? '12'` - закономерно `false`, у вас в массиве не строки, а числа.

Обходной путь - сравнивать пересечением с другим json-массивом:

```
WHERE fieldname @> '[12]'::jsonb
```

Если у вас именно `json` и почему-то изменить нельзя, то оператора `@>` для json нет и надо разбираться, почему нельзя привести к `jsonb`. Если по какой-то уважительной причине нельзя именно поле сконвертировать, то можно преобразовывать налету:

```
WHERE fieldname::jsonb @> '[12]'::jsonb
```

Если же проблема в том, что у вас старая версия `postgresql` и не умеет `jsonb` (до 9.4, то есть) - тогда проблема. Можно написать хранимку, которая будет парсить json и сверять значения.

Answer (score 2):

Сделал вот так:

```
select 
    id,
    param
from (select id, json_array_elements(params)::text as param from table) s 
where param = 12::text
```

Выводит все строки, в которых встречается 12 в json массиве. 
В ответах предложили способ лучше, воспользуюсь им.